# Is it possible to have the same menu than column chooser without the hidding function?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, grid

I want to organize my columns in two categories and to be able to order elements of the first one. I find the column chooser menu really appropriate but my aim is not to hide columns.
Then, is it possible to have a such menu with other options?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Could you describe your requirements more detailed? Do you want to exclude some columns from the column chooser? Do you want to group the columns inside of the column chooser dialog? You wrote that you "want to organize my columns in two categories". Do you use column header grouping ([setGroupHeaders](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:groupingheadar))? Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)?

Comment: Actually i want to creat a treegrid, and to organize my hierarchy thanks a menu like the columnchooser menu (then I don't want to exlude any column). The two categories are for grouped and non grouped columns and the order in the first part in useful to know which level of hierarchy the user want (the first one is the parent, second one is child, third is grandchild...).
At the moment I use this grouping table : http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/

Then, I would like something that looks like the column chooser dialog but with other features.(if something like that exists)

Comment: and I use this free version of jqGrid : http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6
version 5.1.0

Comment: It is not free!!! See [the initial post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438) which declare changing of license agreement (no more MIT/GPL as before). You have access to the open source of Guriddo jqGrid JS, but it's illegal to use it for free. See the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). I started free jqGrid as the fork of jqGrid 4.7 (the last state with MIT license) at the end of 2014 and continue develop it and provide under old MIT/GPL licenses. New features are described in readmes and in many [wiki articles](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki)

Comment: You still wrote common words about "i want ... to organize my hierarchy thanks a menu". What exactly you want to have? Could you specify clear what information you want to have in the column chooser dialog?

Comment: Actually I use it for a personnal project (that's why I said "free" but I noticed that there is a commercial licence).

Comment: I want 2 lists: the first one with data in hierarchy (for instance continent, region, country), the second one with other data (for instance average wage,number of inhabitants...)
And the user could chose to modify the hierarchy (for instance : put number of inhabitants in the fist list)

Then, I just want 2 lists that the user could change easily.

Comment: If you prefer to use Gurrido jqGrid, I'd recommend you to post your question to [Guriddo forum](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=4). I can't help you with Gurrido jqGrid. It could be that somebody else will answer on your question here.